# Custom Function to find the length of array?

Tags: arrays, string, char, string-length

I'm trying to find out the number of vowels in the string but I don't have an idea on finding the length of the uninitialized array. I will iterate through all the array elements and return the no of vowels.I went through the forums and read that there is strlen function that is built in but i want to make my own function understand the working not just having my work done.i've implemented this using a for loop going through all but it was a failure ..

```
char strin[];
printf("Check for the number of vowels in the string : \n");
scanf("%s" , &strin);
int Number_of_vowels(strin);


//a custom function to find the string length.
int string_len(char[] string)
{
    //code to find the length
}
//a custom function to do the check.
int Number_of_vowels(char strin[])
{
    for(i = 0 ; i < stringlength , i++)
    {
        //check if the input char is vowel.
    }
}
```

Comment: If the array is uninitialized then it doesn't have a length.

Comment: You have to add a length argument to Number_of_vowels. The length of a string can be retrieved by strlen(strin);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the return value of scanf.

```
int stringlength;
int vowels;

stringlength = scanf("%s", &strin);
vowels = Number_of_vowels(strin, stringlength);

int Number_of_vowels(char strin[], int stringlength)
{
    int vowels = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < stringlength, i++) {
        // Code testing for vowels (possibly a switch loop testing ASCII values)
    }

    return vowels;
}
```

Comment: Your also still going to have to specify a length for the strin array.  You did it in the above code without realizing it: strin[] = "Hello World!..." C makes strin[] the length of the string + 1.  So you are effectively cutting your input in this case to 31 characters (the array will be 32 with the null character).  If you truly want limitless input, you will have to use buffers and read chunks at a time.  The easiest is just while looping STDIN input until EOF is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry since I cannot comment yet, I'm also on my iPad so formatting would be bad. But why don't you just take the length of `strin[]` when it's passed into `Number_of_Vowels()`?

You already passed the `strin[]` array to it anyways, so the attributes of that array should go into the method as well.

Comment: if its initialized then the user will loose the capability of entering large no.of characters ... I want the char array to be restriction less.

Comment: @AkashChowdary , user can atmost type 31 characters as length of array is 32

Comment: What if i didnt intialise is my question?? what if i didnt intialise the string array??